# Drupal console report that mysql extension needs to be installed

Tags: console

Hi I am a novice at this stuff so that might explain the following:

During my Drupal 8 install I received the following:

> The libmysqlclient driver version 5.6.26 is less than the minimum
>   required version. Upgrade to libmysqlclient version 5.5.3 or up, or
>   alternatively switch mysql drivers to MySQLnd version 5.0.9 or up.

So when I tried to install mysqlnd it was conflicting with mysql, so I carried out the following command `yum remove mysql` and after removal, I installed mysqlnd with `yum install php70w-mysqlnd` (I have php 7 installed)

I was then able to complete the Drupal install, but when I run `Drupal check`, in Drupal console, it reports back:

> The extension mysql is recommended to install

Then when I carry out `mysql -v` the reply is:

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 22
>   Server version: 5.6.31 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Any advice would be welcomed, thank you.

Comment: You possibly have separate .ini files for web/cli, with the extension enabled in/via the web version, but not the cli version

Comment: Hi Clive,So can you direct me as to what I can do?

Comment: `php -i |grep php\.ini` will tell you what .ini file is being used, then it's just a matter of editing that file to uncomment a line like `;extension=mysql.so`. That's assuming my guess was right of course, it might not be. Kind of need access to the server to be sure

Comment: Hi Clive, thank you for the info.  When I check in the php.ini file mysql.so is not listed but mysqlnd.so is. I tried changing the extension=mysqlnd.so (and  uncommenting) but this  gave me the following. PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/msqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/msqlnd.so: cannot open s
hared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0